Nginx is dropping part of request path in the request URL when redirecting after adding a trailing slash
I have a horrible issue with Nginx. I have a service like https://td22-2.test.net/ I use Azure Frontdoor to forward requests from https://example.net/td/22-2/ to it. My Azure Rules are attached The problem is that a part of the url (/td/22-2/) is dropped ONLY when the user enters a URL without an ending slash and Nginx redirects? them to a path with a slash.
For example, when I type https://example.net/td/22-2/example/path will give https://example.net/example/path/ (missing the td/22-2)
I was able to confirm with CURL that /td/22-2/example/path is sent to NGINX with GET, and NGinx returns only /example/path/
server {
    listen 8080;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    root   /opt/24/www;
        gzip  on;
        #I added this to prevent an issue when running it locally where entering a path without a slash would return a path localhost:8080, instead of 81, which is what my docker container exposes.
    absolute_redirect off;
        location / {
           location ~* /images/*.* {
        }
    }
}

I've tried this, and I only added "absolute_redirect off;" to prevent an issue when running this server via docker on my local machine (docker exposes port 81, while the server uses port 8080)

The root cause is that Nginx does not preserve the original request path when it handles redirects without a trailing slash, is it working locally? what is the output of sudo nginx -t
Are you seeing nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
locally? Also share curl output of curl -v http://yourIP:8080/td/22-2/example/path

Hello Arko! No it is not working locally. I get this when I try it locally.

GET td/22-2/example/path


User-Agent: curl/8.8.0

< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
The /td/22-2 is part of the Azure frontdoor domain which is forwarded to this server. The server can handle it just fine. However, when the request is lacking a slash at the end it redirects and gives me a url without the /td/22-2/

first fix it locally, edit the Nginx config for your service, update the configuration to include explicit handling for /td/22-2/ paths and ensure Nginx preserves the full path during redirects, Make absolute_redirect off;
and to handle requests starting with /td/22-2/ location /td/22-2/ {         try_files $uri $uri/ @add_trailing_slash;     } and do a redirect to add trailing slash while preserving the full path location @add_trailing_slash {         return 301 $scheme://$host:8080$uri/;     } and catch all for other paths location / {         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;     }

Once done, save this file and do a sudo nginx -t
You should see nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx.conf test is successful then do a systemctl reload nginx and then test nginx redirection for a URL without a trailing slash
curl -v http://whateverisyourpublicip:8080/td/22-2/example/path like this and this

I added them and it works locally. The result is as your screencaps. Shall I try pushing it to Azure now? I'll give it a try

Yes, give it a try, ensure that Azure Front Door forwards the correct path to Nginx. Set the backend host header to match your Nginx backend, ensure the Front Door routing rule matches /td/22-2/* . Once done then again do curl -v https://example.net/td/22-2/example/path

Heya Arko, sorry for the trouble but there is an error. It's actually where I got caught up before. I've been trying to fix it by myself, but only top level paths seem to be redirecting properly when without a trailing slash.
https://example.net/td/22-2/example -> https://example.net/td/22-2/example/
but if using https://example.net/td/22-2/example/sub1 it's redirected to https://example.net/example/sub1 without the /td/22-2/
I think I should modify the location /techdocs/22r2/ block to accept longer paths?

Unfortunately it seems the last post was wrong. It doesn't seem to work at all.

GET /td/22-2/example HTTP/1.1
Host: example.azurefd.net
< Location: /example/
So even me adding example.net/td/22-2/example sends me to example.net/example
I'm completely lost.


Can you share what rule editing you did in your front door?

Hello Arko! Thanks for the help. I didn't change anything in Frontdoor. However, what I did was I rewrote the server using Rust. That worked for me. I didn't even change much, used the standard webserver.
example.net/td/22-2/example now redirects to example.net/td/22-2/example/
Thank you for all the help!

Good to know, I will update the same as answer for future reference for the SO community

Main issue- nginx was dropping part of the request path during redirects when adding a trailing slash. For example, https://example.net/td/22-2/example/path redirected to https://example.net/example/path/, dropping the /td/22-2/ prefix.
As earlier discussed in comments, this behavior is due to how nginx handles redirects internally. nginx, by default, constructs the Location header during redirects using its internal understanding of the request path, ignoring the forwarded prefix (/td/22-2/) from front door.
Troubleshooting steps that was involved in the process were
first test it out locally and see if everything works fine locally.



As a workaround, instead of modifying Nginx configurations, user, Dineth-Mallawarachchi rewrote the server using Rust. By using a standard web server framework (example actix-web), the issue was resolved without requiring additional configurations. The new server correctly preserved the original request path and ensured that trailing slashes were added as expected. Thanks for your contribution to the SO community, please feel free to edit / add any additional points if required from your end.
